# I Can't call methods in kotlin

Tags: class, oop, kotlin, methods

I am new to kotlin and just starting to learn about classes and methods
but in the code below I can't call the `makeReddit()` method:

```kotlin
class Site( address: String, foundationYear: Int) {
    var address: String = address
    var foundationYear: Int = foundationYear
    
    fun makeReddit(address: String , foundationYear: Int) {
        this.address = "reddit.com"
        this.foundationYear = 2005
    }
}

fun main() {
    val site : Site = makeReddit()
}
```

And I get this error :

```
Kotlin: Unresolved reference: makeReddit
```

Comment: You have to initialize the `Site` first and call the method like `site.makeReddit("reddit.com", 2005)`, but it looks like that method only sets the variables and doesn't do anything else, so you could just use a `data class Site(address: String, foundationYear: Int)` and initialize is via constructor: `val site = Site("reddit.com", 2005)`. Depends on what you are trying to do with that site and year.

Comment: I strongly suggest you go through some Kotlin tutorials (and maybe even java/oop tutorials). You can start with these [tutorials](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials) First you need to grasp the concept on how kotlin/oop works. Otherwise you'll be asking so many questions on StackOverflow on why your code doesn't compile.

Comment: This was  a Task on JetBrains Academy Kotlin Course and the task was just saying There is this class:

`class Site(val address: String, val foundationYear: Int)`
Implement the `makeReddit()` function that returns a Site with the reddit.com address and the foundation year of 2005.

Comment: Your `makeReddit()` method doesn't return anything at the moment... You would have to declare it `fun makeReddit(address: String , foundationYear: Int) : Site { ... }` and in the body really return a `Site`...

Comment: That "JetBrains Academy Kotlin Course" might be too advanced for your right now. First you need to understand what is a `class`, what is a  `function` and what it can do. For instance in your case the task is to add a function which should **returns** something, but you are not returning anything, which might indicate that you are not familiar with **return** concept.

Comment: JetBrains Academy course is just for beginners it takes you from the early start as it teaches you about the Units of information and all of these fundamentals ..... what's above is what happens after 24 hours non-sleeping day :D

Comment: But If you really recommend a certain course what would you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Kotlin, functions do not necessary need to be declared in some class. A function declared outside of a class is called a *top-level* function.

In this task, you can declare `makeReddit` as a top-level function beside the `Site` class:

```
class Site(val address: String, val foundationYear: Int) {
    // ...
}

fun makeReddit(): Site {
    // create and return "reddit" site
}
```

Then you'll  be able to call it just as `makeReddit()` from other places, for example from `main` function:

```
fun main() {
    val reddit: Site = makeReddit()
    println(reddit.address)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> This was a Task on JetBrains Academy Kotlin Course and the task was just saying
> *There is this class: `class Site(val address: String, val foundationYear: Int)`.
>
> Implement the `makeReddit()` function that returns a `Site` with the reddit.com address and the foundation year of 2005.*
> (your comment)

This looks like a task targeting the use of a [`companion object`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/objects-and-companion-objects.html), because you need a method `makeReddit()` that you can use without an instance of a `Site`, like `Site.makeReddit()`.

Here's how you could do it:

```kotlin
class Site(val address: String, val foundationYear: Int) {
    var url: String = address
    var founded: Int = foundationYear
    
    // provide a singleton that creates an instance
    companion object SiteFactory {
        // the fun to be used without an instance of Site
        fun makeReddit() : Site {
            // return the (fix) values of reddit.com
            return Site("reddit.com", 2005)
        }
    }
    
    // provide a String representation
    override fun toString(): String {
        return "$url founded in $founded"
    }
}
```

Then you can create instances of a `Site` in (at least) two different ways:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    // create the reddit site instance directly from Site 
    val reddit = Site.makeReddit()
    // create an instance with different values via constructor
    val random = Site("ran.dom", 2008)
    // and print both of them
    println("reddit: $reddit")
    println("random: $random")
}
```

That `fun main()` will output

```
reddit: reddit.com founded in 2005
random: ran.dom founded in 2008
```